# Prevent MatDialog from being dragged out of the window

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, angular-material

I am currently working on an Angular project. I use the [MatDialog](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview) from Angular material together with the Angular module of [drag and drop](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview). I want to prevent the dialog from being dragged outside of the screen window. Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can set `cdkDragBoundary` to `.cdk-overlay-container` which has the size of the screen.

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-78ofcc-unl6vr-draggable-dialog-with-boundaries)

Comment: This works great for keeping my entire draggable dialog within the screen boundaries.  Is there a way to keep just _some_ of the dialog handle so contained?  I'd like to be able to drag the dialog _mostly_ off-screen with just enough remaining so the user can drag it back on-screen if desired.

Comment: @BrianWhite that requires rewriting `cdkDrag` directive.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you set a box with the size of your screen (like an overlay) and create the drag in drog inside ? Like this example : https://stackblitz.com/angular/omronldbxey?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcdk-drag-drop-boundary-example.ts